# Ruby DynamoDB get_item query failing with ValidationException

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query DynamoDB using the Ruby api.

```
query = {
    table_name : TABLE_NAME,
    key : {
        'foo:bar'.to_sym => {:s => 'value'}
    }  
}
x = @ddb_client.get_item(query) # ERROR on this line.
```

The error is.

```
The provided key element does not match the schema (Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ValidationException)
```

I have a feeling that this is because the hash key of the table is named `foo:bar` with a colon in it's name. I can't use `key : { :index => "value"}` because of this.

I have tried the following values for the key.

- `'foo:bar'`
- `"foo:bar"`
- `:'foo:bar'`
- `:"foo:bar"`
- `"foo:bar".to_sym`
- `'foo:bar'.to_sym`

Still keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the range key in the query.

Our primary index is made up from the hash key, and the range key.

After changing the query to.

```
query = {
    table_name : TABLE_NAME,
    key : {
        'foo:bar'.to_sym => {:s => 'value'}
        'range_key' => {:s => 'value'}
    }  
}
```

It's working as intended.